# WSO2 Identity Server: How to retrieve user's details after oauth

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've set up WSO2IS to use a secondary userstore and have got OAuth2 successfully authenticating against the users in this userstore. I can also see the secondary userstore users' profile information correctly in the admin interface.

However after successfully authenticating via OAuth (using https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), I cannot then retrieve any info for the user. I query the server at /oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid, but it just returns an empty JSON object {}.

How can I retrieve the profile information of the user after successfully authenticating with oauth?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue now. Can you please tell me how you have fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario, you are tring to retrieve user info from google.
Fresh WSO2IS 5.0.0 is shipped with google authenticator which is based on openid.
 But openid is now disabled in google. However, you can use openid connect authenticator in WSO2IS to authenticate 
 with google as google supports for openid connect. But, openid connect authenticator is not capable to retrieving user information from google. 
 This new google authenticator has been added in to the WSO2IS 5.1.0 release already.

please follow the steps below.

1) create new google application

2) Enable particular google API using google developer console and generate client ID and Secret for this application
[image]

3) Go to the Google Identity Provider that you have already created and
please find "Google OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration" under "Federated Authenticators".

4) Tick Enable for "Specifies if custom authenticator is enabled for this Identity Provider" and
Tick Default for "Specifies if custom authenticator is the default".

5) Fill Client ID, Client Secret and Callback Url accordingly.
(note : try to use same “https://localhost:9443/commonauth” url for both Callback Url  and Authorized redirect URIs under “console.developers.google.com” )
[image]

6) Then click on "Update" to save.

7) Set the claims for Identity Provider side "Define Custom Claim Dialect " under "Claim Configuration" > "Basic Claim Configuration" and map "Identity Provider Claim URIs" with 
"Local Claim URIs" to map data sent by Google. 
[image]

8) Same as Identity Provider, set the claims for Service Provider as well."Define Custom Claim Dialect " under "Claim Configuration" > "Basic Claim Configuration" and map "Service Provider Claim URIs" 
with "Local Claim URIs" to map data sent by Google.

(both Identity provider and Service provider particular claim URI should be equal to the local claim URI)